# What is the difference between login and credential in SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, credentials

I am a bit confused SQL server windows login and credential. On books online, it says that credential can access resources beyond sql server, but as far as i see windows login might be able to do that that since it is mapped to a windows user. Am i missing something else?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 20):

***Login:*** 
A login is any principal that is granted access to a SQL Server instance.  The access can be granted to domain users, domain group, or SQL Server authenticated accounts.

***Credential:***
 A credential provides a mechanism to store login information for a domain account within SQL Server.  The credential can then be used to pass that authentication information from into another login or a proxy to grant it permissions to resources external to SQL Server.

**.....use of Login**
if you need to login and access a SQL Server instance, you’ll just use a login.  Regardless of your needs, if you need to get in and do work, the login is through route to go.  The other two won’t help you out at all.

**Use of credentials**..
Credentials get brought in when permissions from domain users need to be granted to accounts or services that wouldn’t usually have those permissions.  For instance, if an assembly required EXTERNAL_ACCESS, those permissions could be granted through the use of a credential.  Credentials can also be used to grant SQL Authentication accounts access to external resources.

Answer (score 12):

A credential is a record containing the authentication information needed to connect to a resource outside of SQL Server. Most credentials consist of a Windows login name and password. On Microsoft Windows Server 2003 and later, the password may not be required.

A single credential can be mapped to multiple SQL Server logins. But a SQL Server login can be mapped to only one credential.

Only users with ALTER ANY CREDENTIAL permission can create or modify a credential.

Answer (score 7):

In previous versions of SQL Server, if there was a need to access something outside of SQL Server the service account under which the SQL Server service was running was the credential that was used. By specifying a credential you can say if user X runs a stored procedure or query which access resource Y, use credential Z as the account to access it.

@Remus Rusanu
You are confusing the idea of a SQL Server login, which is created using CREATE LOGIN, with a different concept called a credential, created with CREATE CREDENTIAL. See http://www.replicationanswers.com/Security2005.asp for more details.

Comment: I don't see any such confusion in his answer, I think you must have misread it, Remus Rusanu worked on the SQL Server team so it is unlikely he would be confused as stated...

Answer (score 4):

Credentials are needs to cover the case when the login is actually *not* a Windows user. Typical case being a SQL Login (user authenticated with SQL authentication instead of integrated authentication).

Answer (score 3):

A credential can also be used to allow SQL Server to access a Windows Azure Blob Storage account.  In this case, instead of storing a Windows login name and password, the credential would store the Azure storage account name as well as the storage account access key.

More details here:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj720554(v=sql.120).aspx

Or here:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn466435(v=sql.120).aspx

This is handy if you want to backup or restore a database from an Azure blob container.